# Market maker hedging model

Tags: equities, spread, hedge, pnl

I understand that most market makers maintain non directionality i.e. they always aim to be perfectly hedged. So if they take a long position in X, they will take an offsetting short position in a hedge Y. My question is however, say that a market maker has inventory of 100 google stocks and he sells 50 google stocks from his own inventory, does this action require hedging? I am a bit confused because I understand that if he were to SHORT the 50 google stocks (i.e. those stocks that he sold were not from his inventory), then there would be a reason for him to hedge this position since he would have to return those stocks. But does a sell position coming from your own inventory require a hedge since after all you're just getting rid of it from your books? Thanks.

Comment: As you point out, if the sell order is filled from your own inventory, you don't necessarily need to hedge. Btw, market-making is not just about keeping your books flat all the time and trying to capture the bid-ask spread. Most of the time, a market-maker would have some *view*: If they think the demand will go up, they would want to build up some inventory in advance. If they feel there will be *demand to sell*, they might want to go short, so when the sell orders come in, these will "naturally" close their shorts.